# How to fix: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ..." on Waze Iframe API using ElectronJS

Tags: javascript, iframe, electron, waze

When I try to use a Waze API on ElectronJS I'm getting this error on the console:

```js
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...
```

If I create an embed on my Chromium, the API works well. But if a get the same code and try to execute inside my Electron app does not work.

Here is my sample code:

```html
<iframe src="https://embed.waze.com/iframe?zoom=13&lat=40.78247&lon=-73.97105&pin=1"
            width="100%" height="520"></iframe>
```

This error does not show the Waze map and I expect that the result works on ElectronJS.

Answer (score 0):

Use the webview tag to embed 'guest' content (such as web pages) in your Electron app. The guest content is contained within the webview container. An embedded page within your app controls how the guest content is laid out and rendered.

Unlike an iframe, the webview runs in a separate process than your app. It doesn't have the same permissions as your web page and all interactions between your app and embedded content will be asynchronous. This keeps your app safe from the embedded content. Note: Most methods called on the webview from the host page require a synchronous call to the main process.

Please try webview:

```
<webview id="webview" src="https://embed.waze.com/iframe?zoom=13&lat=40.78247&lon=-73.97105&pin=1"></webview>
```

More information: https://electronjs.org/docs/api/webview-tag

Comment: Unfortunately, webview does not work too for Waze embed. If I replace the src attribute to "https://github.com" the webview show the page.